# Vue/Vuex > Cannot track state changed when I use Object.defineProperty() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, defineproperty

I use `Vue.js` and `Vuex`.

I make a simple todolist app.

I make a done toggle button with `Vuex` using `Object.defineProperty()` method.

When I click done toggle button, `Vue` and `Vuex` cannot trace change immediately.

It only trace change when I just reassign property's value.

For example

This works:

```
Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todolist: [
            { todo: 'test1', done: false },
            { todo: 'test2', done: true },
            { todo: 'test3', done: false },
            { todo: 'test4', done: false }
        ]
    },
    mutations: {
        ...
        [Constant.DONE_TOGGLE]: (state, payload) => {
            const changeState = state;
            changeState.todolist[payload.index].done = !state.todolist[payload.index].done;
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

But this does NOT work!

```
Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todolist: [
            { todo: 'test1', done: false },
            { todo: 'test2', done: true },
            { todo: 'test3', done: false },
            { todo: 'test4', done: false }
        ]
    },
    mutations: {
        ...
        [Constant.DONE_TOGGLE]: (state, payload) => {
            Object.defineProperty(state.todolist[payload.index], 'done', { value: !state.todolist[payload.index].done });
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

below code trace changes of done toggle only OTHER mutations change state.

Why it does?

Here is my [github repository link](https://github.com/daengdaengLee/vue.js_quick_start).

My app is in `/EX11/todolistapp`.

My Vuex file is in `/EX11/todolistapp/src/store/index.js`

Thanks for reading my question.
Sorry for not good at English.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a Javascript limitation -- Vue [cannot detect changes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) to an element of an array when done via an index.

But why not just grab the todo item and change it's `done` property directly?

```
var item = state.todolist[payload.index];
item.done = !item.done;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It is because I don't want to see 'no-param-assign' alert by eslint :)
I know the reason now.
Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ... is this what you want to achieve?

```
Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todolist: [
      { todo: 'test1', done: false },
      { todo: 'test2', done: true },
      { todo: 'test3', done: false },
      { todo: 'test4', done: false }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
    [Constant.DONE_TOGGLE]: (state, payload) => {
      var val = !state.todolist[payload.index].done
      state.todolist[payload.index] = Object.assign(state.todolist[payload.index], {done: {value: val}})
    },
    ...
  }
})
```